# Insert a new row into DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable filled with staff data like..

```
Staff 1 - Day 1 - Total
Staff 1 - Day 2 - Total
Staff 1 - Day 3 - Total
Staff 2 - Day 1 - Total
Staff 2 - Day 2 - Total
Staff 2 - Day 3 - Total
Staff 2 - Day 4 - Total
```

I want to modify so that the result would be sth like..

```
Staff 1 - Day 1 - Total
Staff 1 - Day 2 - Total
Staff 1 - Day 3 - Total
Total   -       - Total Value
Staff 2 - Day 1 - Total
Staff 2 - Day 2 - Total
Staff 2 - Day 3 - Total
Staff 2 - Day 4 - Total
Total   -       - Total Value
```

to be concluded, I need to insert the total row at the end of each staff record.

So, my question is how to insert a row into a datatable? Tkz..

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
// get the data table
DataTable dt = ...;

// generate the data you want to insert
DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();

// insert in the desired place
dt.Rows.InsertAt(toInsert, index);
```

Comment: I will be looping looping the datatable. so the rows.count will be increasing everytime I insert a new row or.. it will increase only if I write AcceptChanges();

Comment: @william: `Rows.Count` will increase as soon as you insert the row. `AcceptChanges` will reset the `RowState` on all of the new rows so that they do not indicate that they're new.

Comment: Thanks.  But, an ellipses in place of code doesn't help.  But I think I know where you were going, and I should be able to work it out.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 121):

@William You can use NewRow method of the datatable to get a blank datarow and with the schema as that of the datatable. You can populate this datarow and then add the row to the datatable using `.Rows.Add(DataRow)` OR `.Rows.InsertAt(DataRow, Position)`. The following is a stub code which you can modify as per your convenience.

```
//Creating dummy datatable for testing
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("col1", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn("col2", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn("col3", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn("col4", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

dr[0] = "coldata1";
dr[1] = "coldata2";
dr[2] = "coldata3";
dr[3] = "coldata4";

dt.Rows.Add(dr);//this will add the row at the end of the datatable
//OR
int yourPosition = 0;
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, yourPosition);
```

Answer (score 40):

```
// create table
var dt = new System.Data.DataTable("tableName");

// create fields
dt.Columns.Add("field1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("field2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("field3", typeof(DateTime));

// insert row values
dt.Rows.Add(new Object[]{
                123456,
                "test",
                DateTime.Now
           });
```

Comment: perfect solution, tks

Answer (score 6):

```
In c# following code insert data into datatable on specified position

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("SL");
dt.Columns.Add("Amount");

dt.rows.add(1, 1000)
dt.rows.add(2, 2000)

dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.NewRow(), 3);

var rowPosition = 3;
dt.Rows[rowPosition][dt.Columns.IndexOf("SL")] = 3;
dt.Rows[rowPosition][dt.Columns.IndexOf("Amount")] = 3000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, I am using

> DataTable 1.10.5

using this code:

```
var versionNo = $.fn.dataTable.version;
alert(versionNo);
```

This is how I insert new record on my DataTable using **row.add** (My table has 10 columns), which can also includes HTML tag elements:

```
function fncInsertNew() {
            var table = $('#tblRecord').DataTable();

            table.row.add([
                    "Tiger Nixon",
                    "System Architect",
                    "$3,120",
                    "2011/04/25",
                    "Edinburgh",
                    "5421",
                    "Tiger Nixon",
                    "System Architect",
                    "$3,120",
                    "<p>Hello</p>"
            ]).draw();
        }
```

For multiple inserts at the same time, use **rows.add** instead:

```
var table = $('#tblRecord').DataTable();

table.rows.add( [ {
        "Tiger Nixon",
        "System Architect",
        "$3,120",
        "2011/04/25",
        "Edinburgh",
        "5421"
    }, {
        "Garrett Winters",
        "Director",
        "$5,300",
        "2011/07/25",
        "Edinburgh",
        "8422"
    }]).draw();
```

Comment: I think OP was referring to C# not JavaScript - but to your credit they did not specify

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question, which was about the DataTable object in .NET, not the DataTables JavaScript package.