# C# WPF Add a new blank row in the middle of a datatable

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datatable

i have a table in my database that indicate a "rendez-vous". I have a MA and Hours columns.
The MA's column is used to indicate if it's the morning or the afternoon: 1 or 2, 1 for morning, 2 for afternoon. (I can't change the database).

Here is a sample of a result:

```
Hours | MA |Name
10:00:00 | 1 | Robert
10:30:00 | 1 | Jane
11:15:00 | 1 | John
14:00:00 | 2 | Stewart
14:15:00 | 2 | Elton
```

I put it in a datatable:

```
dt = myCon.SelectDataTable(query);
```

Then i binded it to the list:

```
lstGCCCandidatCreneau.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

But before to do that i would like to insert a blank row between the morning and the afternoon. I would like something like this displayed in the list:

```
Hours | MA |Name
10:00:00 | 1 | Robert
10:30:00 | 1 | Jane
11:15:00 | 1 | John

14:00:00 | 2 | Stewart
14:15:00 | 2 | Elton
```

Can i have your help please?

Thanks a lot.

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731622/how-to-insert-a-new-row-into-datatable-in-c)

```
        DataTable dt = SampleData();
        int i = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().TakeWhile(dr => dr != null && dr[1].ToString() != "2").Count();
        DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(toInsert, i);
```

---

```
        public DataTable SampleData()
        {
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Hours",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("MA",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {@"10:00:00", 1, "Robert"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {@"10:30:00", 1, "Jane"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {@"11:15:00", 1, "John"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {@"14:00:00", 2, "Stewart"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {@"14:15:00", 2, "Elton"});
            return dt;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, except when my DataTable don't contain rendez-vous in the afternoon, i have an empty row at the top of the list.

Comment: sorry i wrote an error: i mean: except when the datatable contain only rendez vous in the afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

May be you dont want to add an empty row , and just use grouping in listbox.
You can see a sample [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/)

It may cause lot of other issues, in case you want to use this elsewhere !!!

Comment: i have a problem, in my case this is not a property. It's a column from a database. VS display an error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyApp.exe".

Comment: Arent you creating a Model class which replicates your Database so that you can dump the data when you get it . So ideally you should be using MVVM pattern where in you have a Model class with all the properties similar to your DB and your ViewModel should have a list of Model objects. So you can fill in your List with this and then bind  the listbox to this collection .

Comment: i really like the solution you give, but MVVM is totally unknown to me and i can't rewrite the app. It's a pity.

Comment: Ohh, still you dont need to change the entire app. Only for this scenario also it would work !!! 
You can get a brief idea about MVVM : http://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/simple-mvvm-with-wpf/

Still if you want to use without MVVM: you can convert your datatable to list using :http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784090/Conversion-Between-DataTable-and-List-in-Csharp

and bind your listbox to this list . It would work !!! :)

Comment: Thanks, i'll watch these links.