# unable to figure out index out of range exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I am building data table like this below and when i trying to assign a values to database on row by row basis i am getting  error like this

**there is no row at position 0**

and this is my code:

```
    public DataTable BuildCertInfo()
    {
        DataTable dtCertInfo = new DataTable(TABLE);
        DataColumnCollection columns;
        columns = dtCertInfo.Columns;

        AddColumn(dtCertInfo, ROW_NO, "System.Int32", false, 0);
        AddColumn(dtCertInfo, LIC_ID, "System.Int32", false, 0);
        AddColumn(dtCertInfo, SYS_ID, "System.Int32", false, 0);

         AddColumnString(dtCertInfo, SYS_PART_ID);
         ...............
         ...............
          return dtCertInfo;
    }
```

and i am calling above method like this

```
  DataTable dt = objCertificate.BuildCertInfo();
```

and then i am looping through the gridview and assigning values to data table like below ..

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gvPRCertInfo.Rows.Count; i++)
 {

     dt.Rows[i][Certificate.SYS_PART_ID] = systemPartID; // here I am getting error
     ................
     ................
  }
```

I am not sure where i am doing wrong could any please point me in right direction that would very grateful to me

many thanks in advance ...

Comment: Are you sure `dt.Rows` has enough rows to cover the range of `i`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to fill `dt` with rows with the `for` loop. If that is the case you need to create a new row and add it to `dt` first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a new row into DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731622/insert-a-new-row-into-datatable)

Comment: Should it be : dt.Rows.Count (not gvPRCertInfo)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't create any row, that's why you get the error. Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvPRCertInfo.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
    dt.Rows[i][Certificate.SYS_PART_ID] = systemPartID;
    ....
}
```